# nginx erreur it didn't open

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, nginx

please nginx in my server did start please follow me

```
root@s45-****:/home/arabico# nmap 45.****

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
5/tcp open  smtp
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
root@s45-****:/home/arabico# sudo service apache2 stop
 * Stopping web server apache2                                                      * 
root@s45-****:/home/arabico# nmap 45.****

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-06-05 19:33 MST

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
25/tcp open  smtp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
root@s45-***:/home/arabico# sudo service nginx restart
 * Restarting nginx nginx          
          [fail] 


root@s45-***:/home/arabico# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

root@s45***:/home/arabico# sudo nginx
nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
```

how to let it start please

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: it didn'y work how to let it start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just i deleted this line

listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

from

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
 and it works :D

Comment: I did the same and it also works. But can anyone explain why the default config did not work?

Answer (score 13):

```
nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
```

From the error message this seems ipv6 is disabled on your server.
Edit nginx default server configuration and changed it to listen on ipv4 only or enable ipv6.

```
listen 80 default_server;
# comment to disable ipv6
# listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning ipv6.

In my case, I got a line in nginx conf of

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:3028/;
```

The problem happened when I disable ipv6 in the kernel config. Reenabling ipv6 can solve the problem, but it is not what I want.

the solution is delete

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
```

in `/etc/hosts`.

so the localhost will alway follow the default ipv4 target, which is `127.0.0.1`.

Just deleting the `::1` line could be enough. Since ipv6 is totally disabled, I would delete all of them.

Changing the `localhost` in nginx config to `127.0.0.1` may solve this problem as well.